# How to only get the 'box-shadow-right' that cuts off when you reach a border?

Tags: html, css

how to get a good shadow (AT THE border-right OF THE SMALL DIV) that is equal to the shadow of the large div but that does cut of as it reaches the border-bottom of the small div / the border-top of the large div.
 NOTE: I CANNOT use Z-index, I have a website way more complicated. Also, Spread CANNOT be used here because that doesnt cut off when it reaches the border-bottom/border-top, it won't look 3d anymore.

the html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="small"></div>
<div id="large"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here, the CSS:

```
#small {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
}
#large {
width: 300px;
border: 1px solid black;
height: 100px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

I also have a JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/vijujaweja/edit

-I know, the question is formatted a bit bad, but I hope you understand my question.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just add background color to the divs?

[JS Bin Here](http://jsbin.com/kazowo/1/edit?html,css,output)

```
#small {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:#fff;
}
#large {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:#fff;
}
.dropshadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

Comment: Also, you should be using classes. Have one class for drop shadow and use on all boxes, instead of defining it on each ID. Makes edits a LOT easier.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it like this? http://jsbin.com/xohomaraqe/1/edit I have updated some code.

**Updated**

This should work then

```
#small{
   -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 1px 3px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

Comment: Yea, something like that. But still, you see a very small white stripe right before the shadow ends. I want, that that stripe isnt there. So that the small + the large div is 3d

Comment: Updated Answer. See changes